# How to get to the target # anchor on clicking url (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, url, anchor

I need to get to the #anchor when clicking url.
I used following url, but it doesn't go to the target # anchor.
It only opens customer-service page.
I tried to add tabindex="0" , but still doesn't get to the #anchor (no error in console).
Would you please let me know how to get to the target  # anchor?

Customer-service page:

```
<div  id="faq"></div>
<div  id="feedback"></div>
<div  id="contact-us" tabindex="0" ></div>
```

Url I tried:

```
https://www.myweb.com/en/customer-service#feedback/
```

```
https://www.myweb.com/en/customer-service/#feedback/
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your div area is visible (overflow). Try below structure.

```
<div id="faq" style="overflow:auto;min-height:200px;"> Content 1</div>
<div id="feedback" style="overflow:auto;min-height:200px;"> Content 2</div>
<div id="contact-us" tabindex="0" style="overflow:auto;min-height:200px;"> Content 3</div>
```

URL : https://www.myweb.com/en/customer-service/#feedback

Comment: Hi Vicky: Thank you for your help. I added overflow:auto in div <div class="elementor-element" id="feedback" overflow="auto">, but it still doesn't go to the # anchor. I was wondering if there are any other solutions?

Comment: Hi Vicky: oh.. I found that I added / after the #feedback. Thank you a lot for your advice and help. : )

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your divs properly. It should be...

```
<div  id="faq"> </div>
<div  id="feedback"> </div>
<div  id="contact-us" tabindex="0" > 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Akeellis: thanks you for your hlep. I cloded it, but still doesn't work. Would you please let me know how to solve it?

Comment: The URL you provided in your question doesn't exist.
But anyways, use the first URL and remove the last slash. it should be "https://www.myweb.com/en/customer-service#feedback"

Comment: Hi Akeellis: I tried it but it automatically adds / before # when clicking the button. Would you please let me know how to solve the problem?